# PHPWord - table style defaulting always to Arial 10, new style not being applied

Tags: fonts, styles, phpword

I tried another post here re Title styles not being applied, but that code did nothing, either. Here, my PHPWord builds sections that display hard-coded vars using "Open Sans" successfully; but when I change to displaying info in a Table it always defaults to "Arial" 10. Please see if you can help tell why this is happening, thank you! Note - to get output to show lines evenly from cell to cell i am trying other styles within the text. Even when I apply $BodyFontStyle to each addCell, addText, and addRow, still - Arial only. I need the table to display in "Open Sans" 10. Help, please -

```
$firstRowStyle = array('name' => 'Open Sans', 'size' => 10, 'valign' => 'bottom');
$BodyFontStyle = array('name'=>'Open Sans', 'bold'=>false, 'size'=>14);
$table_cell_style = array('valign' => 'top');
$lineStyle = array('name' => 'Open Sans', 'size' => 10, 'valign' => 'bottom');

//from above, this flag is not set, or set:
if ($signatory_found == 1) { //from mySQL query looking for Signatory.

    $PHPWord->addTableStyle('BodyFontStyle', array('name'=>'Open Sans', 'bold'=>false, 'size'=>14));
    $table = $section->addTable('BodyFontStyle');

    //tried this, to no avail:
    //$PHPWord->addTableStyle($BodyFontStyle);
    //$table = $section->addTable($BodyFontStyle);

    for ($i=0; $i <= $counter; $i++) {
        $table->addRow();
        $table->addCell(1600, $firstRowStyle)->addText("BY:_____________________________________________________");
        $table->addCell(200, $firstRowStyle)->addText('');
        $table->addCell(1600, $firstRowStyle)->addText("     ____________________________");
        $table->addRow();

        $full_name_title = "    " . $signatory_results[$i]['first'] . " " . $signatory_results[$i]['last'] . ", " . $signatory_results[$i]['title'];

        $table->addCell(1600, $table_cell_style)->addText("{$full_name_title}");
        $table->addCell(200, $firstRowStyle)->addText(''); //space between name, and date.
        $table->addCell(1600, $table_cell_style)->addText("                          Date");
    }
} else { //else signatory flag was not set to 1, so no records found.

    $table = $section->addTable('BodyFontStyle');
    $PHPWord->addTableStyle('BodyFontStyle', array('name'=>'Open Sans', 'bold'=>false, 'size'=>14));

    $table->addRow();
    $table->addCell(1600, $firstRowStyle)->addText("BY:_________________________________");
    $table->addCell(200, $firstRowStyle)->addText('');
    $table->addCell(1600, $firstRowStyle)->addText("_______________________");

    $table->addRow();
    $table->addCell(1600, $firstRowStyle)->addText("          Signature");
    $table->addCell(200, $firstRowStyle)->addText('');
    $table->addCell(1600, $firstRowStyle)->addText("                Date");

    $table->addRow();
    $table->addCell(1600, $lineStyle)->addText("     ____________________________________", array(), array('cellMarginLeft' => 6));
    $table->addCell(200, $firstRowStyle)->addText('');
    $table->addCell(1600, $firstRowStyle)->addText("_______________________");

    $table->addRow();
    $table->addCell(1600, $table_cell_style)->addText("          Print Name");
    $table->addCell(200, $firstRowStyle)->addText('');
    $table->addCell(1600, $table_cell_style)->addText("                Print Title");
}

// Hack - Martin/Pitt has a / in the LP Short name which messes up the filename/path
$LPShort = str_replace("/", "-", $LPShort);
$LPShort = str_replace(" ", "-", $LPShort);

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter( $PHPWord, 'Word2007' );
$filelocation = '/var/www/company/contracts/tmp';
$filename = 'Sig_'.$LPShort."_".date('YmdHis',time()).'.docx';
$FullName = $filelocation.'/'.$filename;
//echo $FullName;
$objWriter->save($FullName);

echo $filename;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

THE FIX - i won't post ALL the code again, but this command will show the solution. The key is to put the defined style inline with the addCell command, at the end after the text. Note that, above, i simply had the addCell with the text, but no style after it. i will post a before and after command to explain:

```
/*BEFORE* $table->addCell(1600, $table_cell_style)->addText("{$full_name_title}");

/*AFTER*/ $table->addCell(1600, $table_cell_style)->addText("{$full_name_title}", $BodyFontStyle);
```